# specifying colors manually in leaflet bivariate map within shiny app contex

Tags: r, leaflet, palette, color-palette

Using the code below, I have created a map within the shiny app context. However, as shown in the picture, the polygons' colors are inconsistent with the legend color scheme. I wonder how they can be consistent preferably by changing the legend color scheme. In the code below, the bi_class variable was defined in 9 categories involving a 3-dimensional quantile of x and y variables (i.e, low-low, low-medium, low-high, medium-low, medium-medium, ...).

```
 output$bi_ACSB_BlackP <- renderLeaflet ({


npal2 <- colorFactor(
  palette =  ("Greens"),
  domain = IDD_nhmap$bi_class
)

labels <- sprintf(
  "<strong>Zip Code=%s </strong> <br/> African American (ACS) = %s <br/> African American (Projects)= %s ",
  IDD_mapdata_()$Zip,
  IDD_mapdata_()$Zip_Black,
  IDD_mapdata_()$Zip_Hisp
) %>%
  lapply(htmltools::HTML)

leaflet (IDD_mapdata_(), options = leafletOptions(zoomSnap = 0.25, zoomDelta =
                                                    0.25)) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron",
                   options = providerTileOptions(opacity = 2)) %>%  
  clearControls() %>%
  clearShapes() %>%
  addPolygons(
    fillColor = ~npal2(bi_class),
    stroke = T,
    weight = 1,
    smoothFactor = 0.2,
    fillOpacity = 1,
    color = "black",
    # label=~paste0(NAME," ","County",":"," ",input$sex_map,",", " ",
    #              input$ProjectID,"=",Age,"%"),
    label = labels,
    labelOptions = labelOptions(
      interactive = TRUE,
      style = list(
        'direction' = 'auto',
        'color' =
          'black',
        'font-family' = 'sans-serif',
        # 'font-style'= 'italic',
        'box-shadow' = '3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)',
        'font-size' = '14px',
        'border-color' = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
      )
    ),
    # label=~paste(NAME,"<br>",input$sex_map,
    #              input$ProjectID,"=",Age,"%"),
    
    # label = lapply(labs, htmltools::HTML),
    highlightOptions = highlightOptions(
      #color = "red",
      weight = 2,
      bringToFront = T,
      # color = "#666",
      fillOpacity = 0.7
    )
  ) %>%
  
  setView(lng = IDD_mapdata_1()$long,
          lat = IDD_mapdata_1()$lat,
          zoom = 8) %>%

  bivariatechoropleths::addBivariateChoropleth(
    map_data = bivariatechoropleths::renfrew_county,
    var1_name = pop_2016,
    var2_name = median_household_income_2015,
    ntiles= 3,
    var1_label = "African American",
    var2_label = "Hispanics",
    region_name = "CSDNAME",
    weight = 1,
    fillOpacity = 0.7,
    color = "grey",
    highlightOptions = leaflet::highlightOptions(color = "orange",
                                                 weight = 2,
                                                 opacity = 1)) %>%
  addTiles(options = tileOptions(opacity = 2))
```

})

[image]

Comment: Looking at https://rdrr.io/github/chris31415926535/bivariatechoropleths/man/addBivariateChoropleth.html, seems like you need to add in `bivariatechoropleths::addBivariateChoropleth`, `paletteFunction = npal2` as an argument, otherwise it is using the default palette. 

I cannot reproduce the code myself so I cannot guarantee it works, I am just guessing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggested solution. I got an error by adding paletteFunction = npal2 : Problem while computing `pal_colour = bivar_pal(pal_num)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you declare a function that selects the Green colors like this one should probably work:

```r
palColFun <- function(colorPalette = "Greens", n = 9){
  pal <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n, colorPalette)
  return(pal)
}
```

Then in your code for bivariatechropleth you should add as follows:

```r
bivariatechoropleths::addBivariateChoropleth(
    map_data = bivariatechoropleths::renfrew_county,
    var1_name = pop_2016,
    var2_name = median_household_income_2015,
    ntiles= 3,
    var1_label = "African American",
    var2_label = "Hispanics",
    region_name = "CSDNAME",
    weight = 1,
    paletteFunction = palColFun,
    fillOpacity = 0.7,
    color = "grey",
    highlightOptions = leaflet::highlightOptions(color = "orange",
                                                 weight = 2,
                                                 opacity = 1)) %>%
  addTiles(options = tileOptions(opacity = 2))
```

Ideally you would link palColFun with the same color you generated for the plots, but given the example above, it is not for me to reproduce the example.

Hopefully this works.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! The suggested code returns an error: the condition has length > 1.

Comment: What about using  `paletteFunction = pals::brewer.greens` . Would that work ?